# error checking system type: wrong type argument gnu/linux

Tags: init-file

setting different config options depending on OS. When checking if gnu/linux I get a "wrong type argument char-or-string-p, gnu/linux"

Tried so far:

```
(string-equal (upcase system-type) "GNU/LINUX") 

(string-equal (format "%S" system-type) "gnu/linux") 

(string-prefix-p "gnu" system-type)

(string-equal system-type "gnu/linux")

if(eq system-type 'gnu/linux)

if(eq string= (system-type) 'gnu/linux)
```

None of them worked.

Comment: I use `(if (eq window-system 'x))`

Comment: You can use (symbol-name system-type) to get a string.

Answer (score 1):

The version you were closest to is that one with [`if`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Conditionals.html):

```el
(if (eq system-type 'gnu/linux)
    (progn
      (message "... stuff you want to do under gnu/linux ...")
      (message "1st statement for the then-branch")
      (message "2nd statement for the then-branch")
    )
  (message "... 1st statement of the stuff you want to do otherwise ...")
  (message "... 2nd statement of the stuff you want to do otherwise ...")
)
```

If you want to configure several systems you can use [`cl-case`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/cl.html#Conditionals). Example:

```el
(cl-case system-type
  (gnu/linux
    (message "... stuff you want to do under gnu/linux ...")
  )
  (windows-nt
    (message "... stuff you need under windows-nt ...")
  )
  (t
    (message "Config for unknown system type.")
  )
)
```

That version uses the `cl` library. `cl-case` is autoloaded. So it should work without further configuration.

If you don't want to draw `cl` in you can also use [`cond`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Conditionals.html). Example:

```el
(cond
  ((eq system-type 'gnu/linux)
    (message "... stuff you want to do under gnu/linux ...")
  )
  ((eq system-type 'windows-nt)
    (message "... stuff you need under windows-nt ...")
  )
  (t
    (message "Config for unknown system type.")
  )
)
```